# Is it possible to call a particular function from controller in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I'm a beginner in MEAN stack development and doing a Todo App wherein I'm creating tasksheets and then storing in the todo in that particular tasksheet using angularjs.

Initially, I was just retrieving all the todos without considering to which tasksheet it belongs as well as creating the todos on go. Now I want to enhance it to retrieve the todos for only that particular tasksheet. Since I dynamically want to load the it, I'm using routeProvider with value `'/:TaskID'`, where the TaskID is changing. So if the TaskID exist I'm using a function, otherwise retrieving everything.

Something like this :

```
if($routeParams.TaskID) {
        var id = $routeParams.TaskID;
        Todos.getTodosForId(id)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.loading = false;
                $scope.formData = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
                $scope.todos = data;  // assign our new list of todos
            }); 
    } else {

    // GET=====================================================================
    // when landing on the page, get all todos and show them
    // use the service to get all the todos
    Todos.get()
        .success(function(data) {
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $scope.todos.push(data[i]);
            }
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    }
```

Instead of using the if-else, is it possible to keep them independent? Like I want to keep both of them usable removing that condition. Is it possible to call method over here :
**For particular TaskID :**

```
.when('/:TaskID', 
    {
        templateUrl: "app.html",
        controller: "mainController"
    })
```

**For All Todos :**

```
.when('/', 
    {
        templateUrl: "app.html",
        controller: "mainController"
    })
```

Another question is, how to show todos only for that particular tasksheet while creation of tasksheet?

[image]

As shown in image, my page is showing all the todos, instead of the one which is yet to be created. So instead of showing all the todos, it should initially show me `No Todos`. Once I start adding the todos, I should see only those todos under that tasksheet. I'm a bit confused, on how should I go around achieving it?

Comment: Both are possible, You can create two different routes 'tasks/all' and 'tasks/:taskId' OR define one route tasks/:ID and pass the actual Id or 'All' as parameter and perform IF/ELSE as you do right now.

Comment: Also, you dont need to do `$scope.todos.push(data[i]);` and can skip the for loop entirely by just doing  `$scope.todos = data;`

Comment: Yes, that is possible `tasks/all` and `tasks/:taskId` and even I'm doing a bit of it. But how to call those particular functions? This will drop them to controllers, but what about functions?

Comment: you can just do if/else on $routeParams.taskId, If taskId=='All' fetch all results, else if taskId!='All' then fetch by id.

Comment: Please answer my second question also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call those functions anywhere in your controller and in your template you could attribute them to the `$scope` variable like this:

```js
$scope.cleanForm = function(data) {
    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.todos = data;
};

$scope.loadForm = function(data) {
    $scope.todos = data;
    $scope.loading = false;
};

if($routeParams.TaskID) {
    var id = $routeParams.TaskID;
    Todos.getTodosForId(id).success($scope.cleanForm(data)); 
} else {
    Todos.get().success($scope.loadForm(data));
}
```